# Django models: How do I check that a decorartor property exists

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Profile model with a decorator property

```
@property
    def primary_phone(self):
```

When I query for the primary phone for a given id like this it works

```
x = Profile.objects.get(id=3)
x.primary_phone
```

outputs

```
Out[3]: '+256771000022'
```

However filtering for the same like this

```
Profile.objects.filter(primary_phone="+256771000022").exists()
```

outputs

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'primary_phone' into field. Choices are: _created_at, _modified_at, apierror, business,...)
```

Comment: You should be using fields if you want this behavior to work. `primary_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)`

Comment: I need to use the @property decorator because phone numbers are sometimes prefetched

Answer (score 0):

`@porperty` is a managed python attribute  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property and can not be queried through DB because its data is not part of the DB.

Use a django model field if you need to query it or use Python to handle this attribute after querying the DB.